# Get value of textarea when id is unknown

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I am having a problem with getting the value of a `textarea` which id is populated by values with database. How is it possible to get it with jQuery?

```
function updateTextarea(textarea, updateUrl) {
    var field = textarea.attr("data-field");
    var id = textarea.attr("data-id");
    var fieldValue = document.getElementById(id).value;
    textarea.val("Aktualisiere...");
    textarea.attr("readonly", "readonly");

    jQuery.post(updateUrl, jQuery.param({
        bid: id, 
        bfield: fieldValue
    }), function(data) {
        textarea.empty();
        textarea.val(data);
        textarea.removeAttr("readonly");
    });
}
```

Where I get the `textarea`:

```
$('.arrivalssuper_row').on('focus', 'textarea[data-field="SONSTVEREINBARUNGEN"]', function(e) {
    var textarea = $(e.target);
    updateTextarea(textarea, 'ajax/super_departures_sonstVereinbarungen.php');
});
```

I have tried so far:

```
var fieldValue = textarea.val(); //didnt work
var fieldValue = textarea.value; //didnt work
var fieldValue = document.getElementById(id).value; //didnt work
```

What can I do? Any ideas?

Comment: Many ideas in fact, but you need to show some markup, you can access it through the parent, sibling, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var textarea = $(this);

console.log(textarea.text());
```

Val will not work as it returns a "value" attribute.

Ah, I think I overlooked that we're talking ajax here. The thing is textarea variable doesn't exist in the scope of ajax callback function. You should consider assigning an ID to the textarea automatically (or any other attribute for that matter, but it has to be unique), passing that id with your ajax request, and returning it to ajax callback. Then you can get the textarea again by it's id.

Something like this:

```
$.post(updateUrl, {bid: id, bfield: fieldValue}, function(data){
    $('textarea.'+data.id).text(data.value);
}, 'json');
```

And in your server you'd use sth like (PHP)

```
die(json_encode(array('id' => $_POST['bid'], 'value' => 'whatever')));
```

Comment: it still gives me empty text

Comment: Edited, try this in your on('focus' ... function(){...})

Comment: still giving me empty value., how is this possible?

Comment: if `val()` is not working `text()` will not work and the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: When you're passing the data back from your server, use json object with two fields, like val and id. Then in your callback just do $('textarea.'+data.id).text(data.val).

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki val is not supposed to work with textarea. The error IS somewhere else, but this statement is still incorrect.

Comment: Sorry but no not true, `val()` supposed to work in `textarea` instead of `text()`.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I stand corrected, this is in fact true, both val and text should work, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
var fieldValue = textarea.text();
```

The `textarea` do not have value attribute in them, they have their value between the start and end tag.

Comment: still gives me empty text

Comment: Can you please share your HTML snippet?

Comment: I meant as like other form controls like `input`, textarea do not store its value in value attribute. Yes, we can add a value attribute into textarea.

Comment: No i mean it should work without adding any value attribute (https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/80/).

Comment: Yes, textarea.val(); works as well but @BRG has tried it but it didn't work for him, so I gave him a alternative.

Comment: if `val()` is not working `text()` will not work and the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: guys in my markup i added <textarea class="sonst"> and then what i did was var textarea = $(textarea.sonst).val() and it worked....thanks or all help!!!

Comment: well that is why I asked for HTML snippet. Glad that it was solved.